# Setting ListBox.SelectedItem using custom comparison

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox

I created a class that implements `IComparable<>`. Something like this.

```
public class Entry : IComparable<Entry>
{
    private string Data;

    public Entry(string data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    // Implementation...

    public int CompareTo(Entry entry)
    {
        return Data.CompareTo(entry.Data);
    }
}
```

I then populate a `ListBox` control with these objects.

My expectation was that I could then do something like the following. But this seems to have no effect (and no exception is thrown).

```
Entry entry = new Entry("...");
MyListBox.SelectedItem = entry;
```

I thought it would use my custom comparison code to find the matching item. But if I set a breakpoint in `Entry.CompareTo()`, it never gets hit.

Searching the web, information about setting the `SelectedItem` property seems pretty thin. Can someone explain what is happening here.

Comment: `public class Entry : IEquatable<Entry>`

Comment: @LarsTech: Ok, why does that work but `IComparable<>` does not work?

Comment: IComparable is for sorting.

Comment: @LarsTech: Well, okay. That seems strange that I need two different interfaces for testing for equality and comparing for sorting. `IComparable` can also indicate equality by returning zero. At any rate, I tried implementing `IEquatable<>` and implementing `Equals` but a breakpoint there doesn't get hit either.

Comment: Your code example wouldn't work.  You create a "new" object called entry, and then try to select it.  There is no indication that your "new" object is in that list.

Comment: @LarsTech: Well, if I could use a custom comparer it would. That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do. I'm pretty sure I did this once before, but can't recall some of the details.

Comment: you could override equals and gethashcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing the IEquatable interface instead.  Since you apparently don't care about *object comparisons*, you could just return the result of a String.Equals result on your Data field (which should probably be a property).

```
public class Entry : IEquatable<Entry>  {
  private string Data = string.Empty;

  public Entry(string data) {
    Data = data;
  }

  public bool Equals(Entry other) {
    if (other == null) return false;
    return String.Equals(this.Data, other.Data);
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    return Equals(obj as Entry);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return this.Data.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as we discussed in the comments, I get the same result when I try this.

Comment: @JonathanWood You are doing something I can't see because this worked for me.

Comment: So what does that mean exactly. You tested with the code above? How are you setting `SelectedItem`? Did it work when the item you set it to is not actually in the list? Did you set a breakpoint at your `Equals` method?

Comment: @JonathanWood Yes.  I added items, such as `listBox1.Items.Add(new Entry("one"));` etc.  Then I did `listBox1.SelectedItem = new Entry("two");` and it selected the second item in the list.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I had implemented `IEquatable<>` but was missing the `Equals` override. Still confused why there are so many comparison interfaces when only one is really needed.